# How to know the address of the deep link that redirected to my app in React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, deep-linking

I have a react app which is redirecting to a React native App with this code:

```
      <a href="my.app://">go to my app</a>
```

I want to pass some information to my react native app, so I Need to get the exact address that was called in order to redirect me to the app, how can I accomplish that  both in IOS and Android ?

Comment: If you are using React Navigation, they detailed process here - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Linking component from RN package https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#handling-deep-links

Handling Deep Links
There are two ways to handle URLs that open your app.

1. If the app is already open, the app is foregrounded and a Linking 'url' event is fired
   You can handle these events with `Linking.addEventListener('url', callback)` - it calls `callback({ url })` with the linked URL
2. If the app is not already open, it is opened and the url is passed in as the initialURL
   You can handle these events with `Linking.getInitialURL()` - it returns a Promise that resolves to the URL, if there is one.