# Get the url the app was open with, before any redirects

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, mobile-application

I have an app(let's say Games) that's opened from another app, with an url, for example `myapp://game?id=123"

Games loads by default a certain screen, as seen in the schema below. The url which opens the app is supposed to open `GameScreen` from this Navigation object

```
<Stack.Navigator
  initialRouteName={
    "HomeTabPages"
  }
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false,
  }}
>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="HomeTabPages"
    component={HomeTabPages}
    options={{ headerShown: false }}
  />
  <Stack.Screen
    name="GameScreen"
    component={GameScreen}
    options={{ headerShown: false }}
  />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

The problem is that I can't open `GameScreen`, probably because of the `initialRouteName` default redirect. Is it possible somehow to capture the url with which my app has been open with, and do the redirect to that screen, before the default behaviour?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know the address of the deep link that redirected to my app in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74728697/how-to-know-the-address-of-the-deep-link-that-redirected-to-my-app-in-react-nati)

Comment: The problem here was that there was another navigation stack for the "sign up" flow, which was loaded first, hence my route didn't exist in that navigation stack. The solution was to merge the navigation stacks together and conditionally load them with routes.